# Not able to render partial view as a part of view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

There are a couple of questions I referred on rendering partial views in mvc4. But my problem is that I have a division(DisplayRecords) in my view and want the partial view to open in that division instead of a different view on click of 'view' button.

But that is not happening because in the controller I am returning the partial view because if I return the view, I cannot pass the list containing data.
On returning view, it throws an error that the view cannot accept that type of parameter and the partial view will not work without the list being passed.

I tried assigning the list to a model property and pass that property value to partial view from client side but that throws a null reference exception.

Can someone suggest how I can fix this.

Here is what I have written:

My view:

```html
@model mvcEmail.Models.EmailModel
@*<script type="text/javascript">
   
    var command = document.getElementById("FirstName");
        alert(command);
        if (command == "Value")
            $('#DisplayRecords').load('/Email/Index2');
  
    
</script>*@
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<h2>Index</h2>
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @* @Html.Label(Model.Acknowledge, new { id = "Acknowledge" })
        <br />*@
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { id = "FirstName", @class = "ClassName" })
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { id = "PhoneNumber", @class = "ClassPhoneNumber" })
        <br />

        <input type="submit" name="Command" value="Submit" />
        <input type="submit" name="Command" value="View" />
    </div>
    
    <div id="DisplayRecords">
        @if (ViewBag.query == "View")
        {
            @Html.Partial("Index2")           
        }
    </div>
    
    
}
```

My partial view:

```html
@model IEnumerable<mvcEmail.Models.EmailModel>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Index")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumber)
            </td>

            @*  <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>*@
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

My controller where I am passing list to view:

```html
 if (Command == "View")
            {
                ViewBag.query = "View";
                //var records = new DisplayRecords();

                List<EmailModel> recs = new List<EmailModel>();
                cmd.CommandText = "DisplayRecords";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    model = new EmailModel();

                    model.PhoneNumber = reader["phone"].ToString();
                    model.FirstName = reader["Name"].ToString();

                    recs.Add(model);
                }


                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();

                return PartialView("Index2", recs);

                //return View(recs);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Partial view is not getting its instance of model.You need to provide your model during calling partial view in view as -

```
@Html.Partial("Index2", new List<mvcEmail.Models.EmailModel>(){this.Model})
```

or I will recommend to write another controller action which will return your partial view with model  as -

```
public ActionResult PartialView()
        {
            List<mvcEmail.Models.EmailModel> emailListModel  = new List<mvcEmail.Models.EmailModel>();
            return PartialView(emailListModel);

        }
```

and then call it using -

```
@{Html.RenderAction("PartialView", "Controller_name",null);}
```

This will make your code better as with single responsibility principle.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Ramashanker. both appraoches opened partial view in the view as was required but displayed only the headings not records. This might be because I am not able to pass records list object (recs) to my view, because it throws error on doing so. How do i pass recs to view.

I want to replace -  return PartialView("Index2", recs); with return view(recs);

Comment: I think second option will solve your problem completely. can you post some snapshot of your exception. I think there is problem with <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>. Instead of this use <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstorDefault.FirstName).
        </th>